# Check if Activity is Open Before Displaying Push Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

Hello I have successfully been able to implement push notifications in my app however I have a slight issue I would like to fix.  I have a `NotificationsActivity` that displays a list of all notifications received on the app.

Now if this activity is open there is simply no need for me to display push notifications at the top. So I would like a way to check if this activity is open before doing a push notification.

Is this possible? If yes how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.  You will have to use the ActivityManager.

```
private boolean isActivityForeground( Class activityClass ) {

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();

    return activityClass.getName().equals( tasks.get(0).getTaskInfo().topActivity.getClassName() );
}
```