# how Worker check if an activity is active before sending notification

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android WorkManager API.  And here is the requirement: When a Worker finish the background work, if the app is in foreground, it will not send a notification.  Otherwise, it will send a notification.

I tried the code from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47443019/639616) to check if an activity is active before sending notification.  But it doesn't work.

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    public Result doWork() {
        if (!isActivityForeground(MainActivity.class)) {
            // send notification
        }
        return Result.success();
    }

    private boolean isActivityForeground(Class activityClass) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();
        return activityClass.getName().equals(tasks.get(0).getTaskInfo().topActivity.getClassName());
    }
}
```

When I remove `if`, a notification was sent.

Comment: not sure these may work, could you try to use foreground check in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8490088/10467286)

Comment: @PutraNugraha It works!  Thank you very much.